# common search for vuetify data tables which exists in v-tabs

Tags: datatable, vuetify.js, v-data-table

The Search functionality would also search for a result in any tab data table(each tab contains vuetify data table), not just the tab you are on.

Answer (score 0):

just bind the search in the data table to the text-field model that u use for search. It worked for me

v-tab1 -> bind the data table here to the searchModel
v-tab2 -> bind the data table here to the searchModel

searchModel:''